# Replace/remove text and numbers using PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I cant figure out how to remove the following:

page_item page-item-xxx

xxx = a number.

EXAMPLE:

**I want this :**

```
<?php

$r='some text before page_item page-item-123 some text after';

$r=preg_replace('page_item page-item-[WHAT] ','',$r);

echo $r;

?>
```

**To give back:**

some text before some text after

Comment: Please try to be a bit more specific with your question -- it's difficult to understand exactly how you're trying to modify the original string.

Comment: `/(page_item)\s(page-item-\d\d\d)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very straightforward regular expression. Use `\d+` to match one or more digits on the end. And don't forget a space after the digit group so you don't end up with two consecutive spaces in your output string.

```
$r = preg_replace('/page_item page-item-(\d+) / ','',$r);
echo $r;
// some text before some text after
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that was pretty straightforward :)